# Multicast listener accepting sockets on another port

Tags: c, sockets, udp, multicast

I have a multicast listener in C that is listening on
229.0.0.1, however is accepting UDP sockets destined for 224.0.0.1.

Can someone explain why this is occurring?

The process is bound (server)
to `INADDR_ANY`, and the multicast struct is specified as 229.0.0.1; shouldn't
my "server" process drop UDP datagrams that are not selected for anything other
than what was explicitly configured?

Comment: You should probably add (some of) your code here so it would be easier for everyone to find a solution.

Comment: if you `bind(2)` to `INADDR_ANY` you'll get any packet directed to any local host address (any of the normal IP addressed and any of the multicast)  If you want it **only** to get traffic directed to one of the host addresses (in this case the multicast) you *have to `bind()` your socket* to that address.

Comment: UDP doesn't accept sockets. It reads data.

Answer (score 2):

224.0.0.1 is a reserved [multicast address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address) for addressing all hosts on the local segment.  All network interfaces are always listening on this multicast address.

So if a packet is sent to 224.0.0.1 on the port your application is using, your app will receive the packet whether you asked to listen to that particular multicast address or not.